# jQuery switch checked button to on and off depending on the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

i have a checked button on my view page .... i want to switch the botton from on and off depending on the result .. 
here is the button on my view page

[image]

my code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="1"   class="switch replacement" checked data-text-on="YES" data-text-off="NO">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get('userinfo/newsletter', function (datas) {
    if (datas==1) {
      $('#newsletter')[this.checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('switch replacement replacement');
    }
  });
});
```

but is not working right now... if the button is ON I see this class in firebug which is dynamically created

```
<span class = "switch replacement checked replacement">
```

and if the button is off then the class is

```
"switch replacement replacement"
```

Comment: And what plugin generates that fancy looking button ?

Comment: `checked`is not valid, try `checked="checked"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it

```
 $('input#newsletter').attr('checked','checked');
```

uncheck it

```
 $('input#newsletter').removeAttr('checked');
```

for your span kind the same:

```
$('span.switch').addClass('checked');


$('span.switch').removeClass('checked');
```

combine all those examples togheter where you need and you've done

Comment: @hellosheikh nice have fun! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $(this).attr('value',1);

     }else{
     $(this).attr('value',0);
     }
```